# blender breaks for me

Tags: 3d-view

i think this first happened when i opened up a large file in blender 2.8. i started getting these weird glitchy colored lines and they followed the viewport when it navigated and it didnt look like a seperate mesh was tied to it. i opened up fresh clean files and it still had this glitch on the viewport. i even reinstalled blender 2.8 and it didnt fix it. i opened up a rig today and the rig was glitchy and didnt look normal to fix like when opening up a rig and turning the mesh from a black color to the normal mesh colors by opaque to alpha. this is really frustrating me also because i couldnt find anything on the glitch on the internet. this i feel is my last resort. here's a screenshot of the glitch in action:

[image]

Comment: It looks like the graphics card is at fault.  If the graphics card is too old, or the driver isn't updated, blender can have some pretty crazy artifacts.

Comment: does a cpu have a graphics card?

Comment: the graphics card is what tells the moniter how to display the image, if there wasn't a graphics card you wouldn't see anything.

Comment: Some CPUs have an integrated GPU.